# Virtual Destructor: Not Working?

Tags: c++, virtual-destructor

I am using GNU compiler. The Virtual Destructor in class B does not call the Destructor ~D(). Could anyone tell me why?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class B {
  double* pd;
  public:
  B() {
  pd=new double [20];
  cout<< "20 doubles allocated\n";
  }

  virtual ~B() {   //the virtual destructor is not calling ~D()
  delete[] pd;
  cout<<"20 doubles deleted\n";
  }

  };

class D: public B {
  int* pi;
  public:
  D():B() {
  pi= new int [1000];
  cout<< "1000 ints allocated\n";
  }
  ~D() {
  delete[] pi;
  cout< "1000 ints deleted\n";
  }
  };

int main() {
  B* p= new D; //new constructs a D object
```

Delete should call the virtual destructor in class B but it doesn't.

```
  delete p; 
  }
```

Comment: `cout< "1000 ints deleted\n";` you got a typo there

Comment: This should work (if it compiled, you have a trivial syntax error). What evidence do you have that it doesn't?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It does, you just don't see the output because you've got a typo:

```
cout < "1000 ints deleted\n";
//   ^, less than
```

Your compiler is being too permissive, this shouldn't compile (at least in C++11).

It probably does because [`basic_ios::operator void*`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool) makes a stream object implicitly convertible to `void*` and your compiler is permitting a string literal to decay to `char*` (which is convertible to `void*`). `cout < "x";` then simply does pointer comparison using built-in `operator<(void*, void*)` and throws away the result.